# Debugging systemctl "inactive (dead)"

Tags: systemd, ntp, systemctl

I wanted to determine why `systemd-timesyncd` refused to start at bootup without logging anything or offering useful information in `systemctl status`.

```
# systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
* systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
```

What steps can be done to determine what the issue is in the general case?

Answer (score 2):

After doing a lot of reading of the excellent man files and bisecting a duplicated version of the service (which always "mysteriously worked", non-mysteriously in retrospect).

I discovered there was an unmentioned `Conficts=... systemd-timesyncd.service` with `vboxadd-service.service`.

There was no hint in the logs (presumably `systemd.log_level=debug` would have helped here based upon https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7104).

I was able to notice the conflict only by examining the output of

```
systemd-analyze dot systemd-timesyncd.service
```

which provided the hint of a conflict.

In general you can list all conflicting services using

```
# systemd-analyze dot systemd-timesyncd.service 2>/dev/null | grep red
    "systemd-timesyncd.service"->"shutdown.target" [color="red"];
    "vboxadd-service.service"->"systemd-timesyncd.service" [color="red"];
```

or a command like

```
# systemctl show '*' -p Id,Conflicts | grep -B1 '^Conflicts=.*systemd-timesyncd' | sed -n 's/^Id=//p'
vboxadd-service.service
```